# Workflows not opening in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am unable to create new `workflows` or edit existing workflows in SharePoint designer 2013. Below is the error is get:

[image]

If I try to open again I get below error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the cache of the SP Designer.

Delete the content inside of the following folders:

- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Also some ideas:

- Try to access the workflow from SharePoint Designer installed on another computer.
- Install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2837667
- Install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23072
- Check the update status of your farm in general

Comment: I have already tried deleting the contents inside folder and the hotfix and installing the framework. Nothing worked :-( . Yes from othwer system I can access the workflow in the same site